# f# foldback: Does accumulator need to be the same as list type?

Tags: f#, fold

I have the following code. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why it complains about the second argument to my List.foldback function. It complains that it wants "acc" to be (char * bool * (Direction -> int * int) * int). This does not make any sense to me because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353846.aspx) shows that it simply matches the 'State. In this case, I am trying to make the 'State a "Movement list".

For a full description of what I am doing, please visit [the Code golf voronoi problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/make-a-voronoi-diagram-ascii-variant)

```
type Direction = Left=0 | Up=1 | Right=2 | Down=3
type Movement = (char * (int * int) * Direction)

let rec masterClaims (items:Movement list) =
    items

    // Execute these methods in the order in which they are passed. 
    |> List.map (fun (ch, coord, dir) -> 
        (
            ch,
            // This function does the claiming. This has to be 
            // done in the order of the input list. 
            claimCells ch coord,
            getCoordinate coord,
            int dir
        ))

    // Create next items and fold them into the final results for the layer. 
    // Use foldback so that they are pre-pended to the final list in the correct
    // order.
    |> List.foldBack (fun (ch, wasClaimed, getCoordinate, directionInt) (acc:Movement list) ->           
        if (wasClaimed) then

            // Create a list of next nodes to inspect
            // [counter-clockwise; forward; clockwise]
            [(directionInt+3)%4;directionInt;(directionInt+1)%4]
            |> List.map enum<Direction>
            |> List.iter (fun direction ->
                (
                    ch, 
                    getCoordinate direction, 
                    direction
                ) :: acc |> ignore)

        acc // should be  Movement list
        ) List.empty<Movement>


    // The theory here is that we will execute the fold
    // for every item before we pass the entire collection
    // to the recursive call. 
    |> masterClaims
```

The code with Tomas' fix

```
let inline foldBackNormal f s input = List.foldBack f input s 

type Direction = Left=0 | Up=1 | Right=2 | Down=3
type Movement = (char * (int * int) * Direction)

let rec masterClaims (items:Movement list) =
    items

    // Execute these methods in the order in which they are passed. 
    |> List.map (fun (ch, coord, dir) -> 
        (
            ch,
            // This function does the claiming. This has to be 
            // done in the order of the input list. 
            claimCells ch coord,
            getCoordinate coord,
            int dir
        ))

    // Create next items and fold them into the final results for the layer. 
    // Use foldback so that they are pre-pended to the final list in the correct
    // order.
    |> foldBackNormal (fun (ch, wasClaimed, getCoordinate, directionInt) (acc:Movement list) ->           
        if (wasClaimed) then

            // Create a list of next nodes to inspect
            // [counter-clockwise; forward; clockwise]
            [(directionInt+3)%4;directionInt;(directionInt+1)%4]
            |> List.map enum<Direction>
            |> List.iter (fun direction ->
                (
                    ch, 
                    getCoordinate direction, 
                    direction
                ) :: acc |> ignore)

        acc // should be  Movement list
        ) List.empty<Movement>


    // The theory here is that we will execute the fold
    // for every item before we pass the entire collection
    // to the recursive call. 
    |> masterClaims
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `List.foldBack` function is a bit odd in that it takes the input list as the argument *before* the last one and the initial state as the *last* argument. So switching the order of the last two arguments should fix the problem. Alternatively, you can define a helper with switched order of arguments and use that:

```
let foldBackNormal f s input = List.foldBack f input s
```

This is for historical reasons (compatibility with OCaml), but I'm sure you're not the only one who finds this confusing :-).

Comment: @Dmitry How do I do that?

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens `let inline foldBackNormal . . .`

Comment: @Dmitry [This is interesting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx). I did not realize that this keyword existed. Thanks.